# Why is Validator.TryValidateObject slowing down exponentially

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I query a remote service to receive a batch of 100 products at a time and continue to do this until no more batches remain. I remap these 100 products to my own product object which I wish to validate and save to a database one at a time. If one doesn't validate I log the error and continue with the rest. Once the first 100 have been processed I go and get the next batch of 100. There are about 5000 in all.

The issue I'm seeing, after profiling my website, is that the **Validator.TryValidateObject** seems to exponentially take longer and longer to run. The first batch of 1000 took 10 mins, the second 1000 took 20 mins, the third 1000 took 30 mins. So it seems to take 10 mins longer each time.

The Product class has a buddy class ProductValidation with the appropriate data annotations for validation. I call product.IsValid().

```
    public class Product{
        public bool IsValid()
        {
            return this.IsValid<Product, ProductValidation>();
        }
    }
```

Using the following code:

```
    public static bool IsValid<T, U>(this T obj)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(U))
        {
            TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(T), typeof(U)), typeof(T));
        }

        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(obj, null, null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        //The line below slows everything down. If commented out all is fine
        Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, validationContext, validationResults, true);

        if (validationResults.Count > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Why would the above scenario slow down exponentially? It's like the validator is re-validating all objects each time.

Comment: Try calling `AddProviderTransparent` only once for each pair of types.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is quadratic runtime, where the cost per unit work increases linearly with the amount of work done.

The most likely explanation I can see is that `AddProviderTransparent` extends a list which has linear search time, either because it uses linear search, or because there's a hash collision and linear search through the bucket.

If you add one new provider for every unit of work, and process the entire list of providers for each unit, then you get quadratic runtime.

Instead of extending the provider list on every call, do so only when the required provider isn't in the list yet.  You could use a `HashSet<Pair<Type, Type>>` to remember what `T, U` pairs you've already added.

Comment: Tried this but I'm afraid it didn't work but thanks for a good suggestion!